# With react-oidc-context, how can I remove authentication and tokens?

Tags: openid-connect, react-oidc

When the user logs out I call

```
const auth = useAuth();
...

auth.clearStaleState();
auth.revokeTokens();
auth.removeUser();
```

However when the user attempts to reach a protected route they show as still authenticated and their tokens are still set.